# Save Data in blob from Java code

Tags: java, mysql

I am using below Java code to save data into a table

```
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
     ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(string));
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String query = "Insert into Test(window,windowObject) values (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        pst.setString(1, "harom");
        pst.setBinaryStream(2, ois);
        pst.execute();
}
```

But Getting below exception

> SEVERE: >>java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
>
> > > at test.DragDropViewModel$1.execute(DragDropViewModel.java:62)
> > >          at com.csdcsystems.amanda.transaction.Transaction.executeCommand(Transaction.java:164)
> > >          at test.DragDropViewModel.testConnnection(DragDropViewModel.java:48)

Anyone Know WHat i am doing wrong ?
My Table definiton

```
window  varchar no  8000
windowObject    text    no  16
```

Using these driver

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking ta your code

```
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, "harom");
        pst.setBinaryStream(2, ois);
        PreparedStatement pst =  connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, "harom");
        pst.setBinaryStream(2, ois);
        pst.execute();
```

why there are two same set of lines? is it a typo from you? it should be

```
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, "harom");
            pst.setBinaryStream(2, ois);
            pst.execute();
```

Also `windowObject` column should be `blob`/`binary` instead of `text`

Other than that
This error usually occurs because your JDBC driver implements an older version of the JDBC API than the one included in your JRE. These older versions are fine so long as you don't try and use a method that appeared in the newer API.

I recommend upgrading it to the version that was released with your database version and try again.

Comment: added driver which i am using

Comment: what about other points. Did they helped ? I mean 1st and 2nd point.

Comment: I drop previous table and updating create table Test (window varchar(100),windowObject image);  have to update Jar as well?

Comment: Check what is the latest JDBC driver for the version of your database for example oracle 11g. Make sure you are using the latest. And as you are saving binary data change your column to blob/binary. Then try.

Comment: I have change my column but still same exception 'create table Test (window varchar(100),windowObject image)'

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: I am using MSSql Server 2008

Comment: In MSSql do you have blob as datatype?

Comment: Also what web server you are using ?

Comment: If you are using lower version of tomcat then this may happen. Make sure you use tomcat 7.

Comment: I am using TOmcat7 and other table also using blob datatype but we are using JOOQ for other place i am just creating a demo with JDBC

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractMethodErrors` are thrown when the method does not exist on the implementation. I'm guessing you have a version mismatch between the JDBC interfaces (from the core java API) and the JDBC driver. It's likely that the driver you are using was created before `setBinaryStream` existed.

I'm guessing you'll be able to use `PreparedStatement.setBlob(...)` instead.